# Lottie player not loading when used as js module

Tags: javascript, lottie

I am trying to use lottie player web component. I have followed their instructions on [github](https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-player) and installed it with npm:

```
npm install --save @lottiefiles/lottie-player
```

Added lottie player to html like this:

```
    <header>
        <div>
            <lottie-player 
                src="https://assets7.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/gbQKQKT9Z0WGdT9/data.json"  
                background="transparent"  speed="0.5"  
                style="width: 30px; height: 30px;"  
                loop 
                controls 
                autoplay>
            </lottie-player> 
        </div>
        <h1>SIM</h1>
    </header>
```

And in my main.js file I am importing lottie-player:

```
import "@lottiefiles/lottie-player";
```

But, the lottie player is not loaded in the html that way. When I import the script with CDN then it works. How can I make it work with the import to my js files?

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses `lottie-web` instead of `lottie-player`

```
import React, { useEffect, createRef } from 'react';
import lottie from 'lottie-web';

const LottieWrapper = () => {
  let animationContainer = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const anim = lottie.loadAnimation({
      container: animationContainer.current,
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: true,
      autoplay: true,
      // animationData: // local json file,
      path: 'https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_6UVhfF.json',
    });
    return () => anim.destroy(); // optional clean up for unmounting
  }, [animationContainer]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Bodymovin Animations in React</div>
      <div className="animation-container" ref={animationContainer} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LottieWrapper;
```